# send two lists in my template, for' tag received an invalid argument: for i in liste ; j in liste2

Tags: python, django, listview, django-forms, django-templates

I want to send two lists in my template, I used this syntax {% for i in liste ; j in liste2 %} and I got the following error : 'for' tag received an invalid argument: for i in liste ; j in liste2

my template

```
{% for i in liste ; j in liste2 %}
        <tr>
         <td> M {{ forloop.counter}}</td>
         <td>{{j}}</td>
         <td class="text-error">{{i}} </td>
        </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

could someone help me

Comment: Are you expecting inner loops? For each element of `liste` do you want to iterate all elements of `liste2` ?

Comment: I do not want to do a inner loop, just want to view the contents of list1 and list2, knowing that they are the same size

Comment: Why would you think this would work? It's not valid syntax in Python or in Django templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip(). 
In your views, you can write this.

```
l = zip(liste, liste2)
```

and in your template, you can write `{%for i, j in l%}`